# Primary index is not used in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, hibernate

I am not an expert in mysql and I don't understand why the primary index isn't used.

create table script:

```
create table BVorgang(
    Id bigint NOT NULL,
    Status varchar(2) NOT NULL,
... 
    SysVersion int NOT NULL,
    SysUserIn varchar(32) NULL,
    SysUserUp varchar(32) NULL,
    SysStampIn datetime NULL,
    SysStampUp datetime NULL);
alter table BVorgang add constraint PK_BVorgang primary key (Id);
create index IND_BVorgang_Status on BVorgang (Status);
```

hibernate generated query:

```
select count(id) from BVorgang where id in (select vorgang1_.id from BVorgang vorgang1_ where vorgang1_.status in ('20' , '30' , '70' , '40' , '75') group by vorgang1_.id);
```

I have a developer system mac os with a mysql database 5.6 and I get the following and expected result:

```
mysql> explain extended select count(id) from BVorgang where id in (select vorgang1_.id from BVorgang vorgang1_ where vorgang1_.status in ('20' , '30' , '70' , '40' , '75') group by vorgang1_.id);
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type   | possible_keys               | key                 | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | BVorgang  | index  | PRIMARY                     | IND_BVorgang_Status | 4       | NULL               | 5144 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vorgang1_ | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IND_BVorgang_Status | PRIMARY             | 8       | fmtest.BVorgang.Id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> select count(id) from BVorgang where id in (select vorgang1_.id from BVorgang vorgang1_ where vorgang1_.status in ('20' , '30' , '70' , '40' , '75') group by vorgang1_.id);
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|      5074 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0,02 sec)
```

The other machine is an ubuntu 12.04 test server (4 cores 7 gb ram) with an installed mysql 5.5. If I run the query on this machine I get the following an unexpected result:

```
mysql> explain extended select count(id) from BVorgang where id in (select vorgang1_.id from BVorgang vorgang1_ where vorgang1_.status in ('20' , '30' , '70' , '40' , '75') group by vorgang1_.id);
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table     | type  | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                    |
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | BVorgang  | index | NULL                | IND_BVorgang_Status | 4       | NULL | 2228 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | vorgang1_ | range | IND_BVorgang_Status | IND_BVorgang_Status | 4       | NULL | 2039 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(id) from BVorgang where id in (select vorgang1_.id from BVorgang vorgang1_ where vorgang1_.status in ('20' , '30' , '70' , '40' , '75') group by vorgang1_.id);
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|      2036 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1.59 sec)
```

I have no idea, why the primary index isn't used on the second machine. Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Try index hint `select count(id) from BVorgang USE INDEX (PRIMARY) where..`

Comment: @Mihai: Unfortunately is the not "possible". The query is generated by hibernate and the last thing that I want to do is, changing source that runs on correctly on many other systems.

Comment: Can you post the code that is generating this hibernate query as well as the object that you are counting please. This will help us debug your problem

Comment: @JamesMassey: I don't think that you need the hibernate code, because the problem can by reproduced in pure SQL. The question is - why is the mysql server working like this? It has nothing to do with hibernate - is just an sql problem.